# Django using a variable in multiple views/templates

Tags: python, django

I have a table with results from a search. This means there are no models here. The problem is that i'd like to go to a detail page for a clicked item, but I am not sure if I can do that without putting it in the URL.

Right now it is done like this:

In my .html for each item in the table:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' title=item.name %}">view more</a></td>
```

In my urls.py

```
url(r'^track/(?P<title>.+?)/$', detail,
            name='detail'),
```

In my detail view, where it uses the variable:

```
def detail(request, title):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ...
```

Now this might work, but it is not ideal for me. The url contains whitespace and is not urlencoded, because I need the variable like it is. I was wondering if there is some easier, or better way to pass this variable to a different view or template

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to define a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method on the model class for your `item` model. This is typically done using `reverse`, so it would look something like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'title': self.title})
```

Then in your template you simply do:

```
<a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">view more</a>
```

And the title will be properly escaped.

That said, you might want to consider using a [slug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) instead of a title to generate your URLs.